# FlowDocument table databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, flowdocument

I'm trying to use the code from the following sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx

to dynamically create FlowDocuments with a table bound to xml.
The problem is that I first load the template and only then set the Databinding (because I use different data each time).

Anybody knows how to modify the code (maybe react to another event?) to make the code
from this example trigger code generation after the "dynamic" datacontext is set?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so you are using the 'BindableRun' class and are never getting bound?  I recently encountered the same problem.  You can trigger the data binding by updating the layout on any 'UIElement' object tied to the same dispatcher.  The object does not even need to be in the visual tree - it is just invoking the context layout manager shared by all objects using the same dispatcher.

Simple example:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.UpdateLayout();
```

To get an accurate page count from the document paginator, you should update the layout first.  Be careful though, as updating the layout again later will also invalidate any document paginators tied to the same dispatcher.

Comment: followed a different strategy, but thanks! will try if have an opportunity.